# Accessing JavaScript variable in Quotations

Tags: javascript

Dynamically, Iam getting the value of a dropdown from database using hidden input values.

```
floor_data=$("#floor_id").val()
```

Now , Iam fetching **floor_data** value as integer such as 14. I have to put this value to another dropdown (I have to prepopulate).

```
$("#selectedEmployeesdata").val(floor_data);
```

But , its not working because we have to pass the value as `.val("14")` , Iam passing it without quotes.If I put it in quotes, I can't access the `floor_data` value

Hope, You understood my requirement.

Comment: The quotes should make no difference in this case, and what you have should (and does) work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/fpuopky2/. Could you show an example of your HTML

Comment: If you want to pass a String : $("#selectedEmployeesdata").val(floor_data.toString());

Comment: @oliv37 `val()` already returns a string

Comment: so what is the OP problem ? your variable is undefined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a string use `String()` built-in JS function:

`$("#selectedEmployeesdata").val(String(floor_data));`

Comment: `val()` returns a string

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are wrong, execute this example : `<progress value="50" max="100" id="prog"></progress>
...
alert(typeof $("#prog").val()) // number `

Comment: Fair point, however the type returned makes no difference when setting the value of the select: https://jsfiddle.net/fpuopky2/1/

Comment: he is using hidden, i will check now if hidden can return a number.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in this case `String()` won't help, hidden return string. i saw that data- attribute return also number if there is a number inside so i thought val have the same behavior.